# Test failing with Integrity constraint violation error, but on the first test case it passed. Why?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a test. It keep failing with this error:

```
   FAIL  Tests\Feature\WorkfieldTest
  ✓ index should be accessible by internal
  ⨯ index should be accessible by customer
  ⨯ index should be accessible by employee
  ⨯ index should not be accessible by guest

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myapp`.`workfields`, CONSTRAINT `workfields_specialization_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`specialization_id`) REFERENCES `specializations` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `workfields` (`specialization_id`, `server_generated`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 1, 2020-11-18 18:55:50, 2020-11-18 18:55:50))
```

I have googled it and read similar questions here and there but still can't find the appropriate answer. I have defined and call the seeders on `setUp`, respecting the order of the table. The first call of test method are passed, the rest is failing. I see that the error has an insert call, meanwhile my test case is doing nothing but to get and count the data from it. So, what happened here?

`Test`

```php
class WorkfieldTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    private $internal;
    private $customer;
    private $employee;
    private $count;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->app->make(PermissionRegistrar::class)->registerPermissions();
        $this->seed(RolesAndPermissionSeeder::class);
        $this->seed(SpecializationSeeder::class);
        // dd(Specialization::count()); -> 68
        $this->seed(WorkfieldSeeder::class);

        $this->internal = User::factory()->create()->assignRole('internal');
        $this->customer = User::factory()->create()->assignRole('customer');
        $this->employee = User::factory()->create()->assignRole('employee');

        $this->count = Workfield::count();
    }

    public function testIndexShouldBeAccessibleByInternal()
    {
        $this->actingAs($this->internal, 'api')
            ->getJson(route('workfields.index'))
            ->assertOk()
            ->assertJsonCount($this->count);
    }

    public function testIndexShouldBeAccessibleByCustomer()
    {
        $this->actingAs($this->customer, 'api')
            ->getJson(route('workfields.index'))
            ->assertOk()
            ->assertJsonCount($this->count);
    }

    public function testIndexShouldBeAccessibleByEmployee()
    {
        $this->actingAs($this->employee, 'api')
            ->getJson(route('workfields.index'))
            ->assertOk()
            ->assertJsonCount($this->count);
    }

    public function testIndexShouldNotBeAccessibleByGuest()
    {
        $this->getJson(route('workfields.index'))
            ->assertUnauthorized();
    }
}
```

`Migration`

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('workfields', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('specialization_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->boolean('server_generated')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('workfields');
}
```

Comment: Seems like maybe the database is not getting cleared after the first test, and insert fails on subsequent tests? The `RefreshDatabase` trait should do that for you though. You do have a separate database defined in `.env.testing`, yes?

Comment: Try running each failed test separately  - like only first failed test only, second failed test only, third failed test only and so on. What I feel is that when the first failure occurs, the db records seeded in the `setUp` method do not get cleaned hence all the subsequent tests also fail. So first run `php artisan migrate:fresh` and then run all tests separately

Comment: @miken32 , no, i have not separated my database for test, i also don't have `.env.testing` file on the project. As for the `RefreshDatabase`, i have similar thought but don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Donkarnash , Okay let me try that and I'll let you know if it fixes the problem

Comment: @Donkarnash , I did your advice and move my seeds and factories to each related test case. still having the same error

Comment: @DonnyPratama So when you run each test separately all fail?

Comment: @Donkarnash all fail, only last one succeed since there is no use of seeder

Comment: @Donkarnash my bad, used a wrong class on the seeder, i fixed it, now it was only the first and the last one succeed

Comment: @Donkarnash please have a look https://imgur.com/a/r3ZBlVw

Comment: Am unable to identify the problem. If you can create a repo on github maybe changing some names or so then I can have a look at it and actually test it to identify the issue. If okay you can send me the repo link on neerav[at]thinkstudeo[dot]com

Comment: @Donkarnash , sure I'll create a new repo for it.

Comment: @Donkarnash , I've sent you a mail, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test file runs without error when using in-memory sqlite database by uncommenting the below two lines in standard `phpunit.xml` that comes with Laravel installation

```xml
    <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

However while testing against MySQL it fails as you mention. Probably the seeders running before each test is a problem - as your seeders contain fetching data from json files and then converting them to associated array before running `Model::create()`. With in memory database such problem is not encountered but with MySQL the problem arises somehow.

There are two ways to get around this. First most simple way is to include call to run all seeders in `DatabaseSeeder` class and then set the value of `$seed` property to true on the test class where you need the seed data - more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#using-seeds)

```php
class WorkfieldTest extends TestCase
{
   use RefreshDatabase;

   /**
    * Indicates whether the database should be seeded before each test.
    *
    * @var bool
    */
    protected $seed = true;

   //... tests
}
```

The other option is to run the seeders with data fetched from json files only once before all tests by setting a static variable on the class and using it to control that certain seeders are run only once for all tests in the class.

```php
class WorkfieldTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;


    protected static $initialized = false;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->app->make(PermissionRegistrar::class)->registerPermissions();
        $this->seed(RolesAndPermissionSeeder::class);

        if (!static::$initialized) {
            $this->seed([SpecializationSeeder::class, WorkfieldSeeder::class]);
            static::$initialized = true;
        }
    }

   //... tests
}
```

Either of the above two will allow the tests to run with MySQL/Sqlite without any error.

Comment: You're my hero! ️